# Sass mixin to prepend to selector

Tags: sass, mixins

Is it possible to make a SASS mixin to prepend its output to the selector? I use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to check for svg capability of the browser. It outputs the `svg` class to the `<html>` element when svg is supported.

I would like the `background-image` to change depending on the svg capability. Basically, this is what I need:

```
.container .image { background-image: url('some.png'); }
html.svg .container .image { background-image: url('some.svg'); }
```

What I would like to have in my SCSS is a mixin that I could `@include` in the following way:

```
.container {
  .image {
    background-image: url('some.png');
    @include svg-supported {
      background-image: url('some.svg');
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of having to write:

```
.container {
  .image {
    background-image: url('some.png');
  }
}

@include svg-supported {
  .container {
    .image {
      background-image: url('some.svg');
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand).

It is possible by using the ampersand & sign. For reference, the needed mixin in this case is

```
@mixin svg-supported {
  html.svg & {
    @content;
  }
}
```

This can be used in the following way:

```
.image {
  background-image: url('some.png');
  @include svg-supported {
    background-image: url('some.svg');
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI: This is great when all you want to do is add another class modifier to the _content_ of one selector.  If you want to prepend that class modifier (or a new selector entirely) to a chain/hierarchy of selectors, it seems you are out of luck - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230430/how-to-modify-the-root-parent-selector-in-sass

Answer (score 0):

For those who see this by searching, I'd like to improve @RJo 's answer to adding support for root inclusions of this mixin:

```
@mixin svg-supported {
  $parent-selector: &;
  @at-root html.svg #{$parent-selector} {
    @content;
  }
}
```

This way it'll work even if you include the mixin at the root of your file like this:

```
@include svg-supported {
  background-image: url('some.svg');
}
```