# How to modify the root parent selector in sass

Tags: sass

How can I modify the root element of the parent selector chain?  (using sass 3.3.x) Something like...

```
=prepend($prefix)
  @at-root .#{$prefix}#{&}   // note there is no dot (.) separating it
    @content

.foo
  .bar
    +prepend(baz)
      background: red
```

and return

```
.baz.foo .bar {
  background: red;
}
```

or even better... an explicit way to target the root element (or even the nth element)?

Comment: Same problem here.  It seems SASS only supports the simpler use-case where you wrap the content of the current selector with another class, ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563128.  This would be really handy for inlining browser- or device-specific overrides within larger sets of rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
=prepend($prefix)
  &.#{$prefix}
    @content

.foo
  +prepend("baz")
    .bar
      background: red
```

Returns this:

```
.foo.baz .bar {
  background: red;
}
```

On the right track?

Comment: i want to be able to prepend to the root anywhere in the tree.  this solution works only if the mixin is used directly from the parent you want to prepend.

Comment: @brewster so what are the conditions under which it will trigger different results? more examples of your expectations would be helpful.