# Can I get the root selector via sass mixin?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Is there a way to target the "root selector" via sass's mixin? (not the `@at-root` selector)

For example:

```
.wrapper  {
    background-color: yellow;
    .field{
        @include root {
            .x{
                background-color: red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

outputs this

```
.wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.wrapper .x {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: it's a strange question (or I might have not understood it) ^^ The :root selector (which is the same as html selector) is the most top selector. So it will have an effect only if it's the first one in your nesting ... OR if you want to prepend it to your current nesting level (here ".field") you would do **:root & .x**

Comment: For the mixin part, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563128/sass-mixin-to-prepend-to-selector)